Why is Xcode corrupting SVG images in the asset catalog?
In a large project I'm working on for a client, a designer provided SVG images that I dragged into the asset catalog in Xcode. The files look good in the finder, but they show up corrupted in the asset catalog, and manifest the same problem when running in the iOS simulator (and presumably on device.) In one case the coloring is wrong, and in another, some of the vector content in the middle "foreground" of the image is clipped. The image contents are correct at the edges, as are the contents drawn behind that clipped part.
If I instead open the SVG file in Xcode using the finder's "open with" option, it looks correct.
Is Xcode's/iOS's ability to render SVG vector images fragile? Are others having this problem?
The designer re-generated the image using Adobe Illustrator rather than XD and the Illustrator version renders correctly. Unfortunately the XML in the Illustrator version does not have any formatting (carriage returns, indentation, etc.) so it is just about impossible to read, and I also can't easily compare the good and bad versions since their formatting is so radically different.
(Unfortunately the images are proprietary so I can't share the image files.)

iOS has no native SVG support, so how is this supposed to work?

"Is Xcode's/iOS's ability to render SVG vector images fragile?" -- Yes :(

There are plenty of online XML formatters and offline tools

Matt, I'm not sure how it works under the covers, but in recent versions of Xcode it more or less works (problem images notwithstanding.)

@DuncanC - side note: I ran into similar issues when exporting .svg from Sketch. Opened the .svg in Inkscape, exported (without any modifications), and then had success when adding to Asset Catalog.

Good to know. Unfortunately my client keeps their developer machines locked down tighter than a drum. I don't have access to public GitHub, or the ability to install anything but approved apps.

In my case inkscape added the problem (the svg looked cropped) so i exported to PDF from inkscape and the problem was solved.
